# Saving a pymupdf fitz object to s3 as a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pymupdf

I am trying to crop a pdf and save it to s3 with same name using lambda. I am getting error on the data type being a fitz.fitz.page

```py
import os
import json
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import fitz, sys
from io import BytesIO

OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ["OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME"]
OUTPUT_S3_PREFIX = os.environ["OUTPUT_S3_PREFIX"]
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = os.environ["SNS_TOPIC_ARN"]
SNS_ROLE_ARN = os.environ["SNS_ROLE_ARN"]


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    textract = boto3.client("textract")
    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        filename = unquote_plus(str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"]))
        
        doc = fitz.open()
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        obj = s3.Object(bucketname, filename)
        fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        pdf=fitz.open("pdf", stream=BytesIO(fs))
        #pdf.close()
        
        
        rect=fitz.Rect(0.0, 0.0, 595.0, 842.0)
        #page = pdf[0]
        page1 = doc.new_page(width = rect.width,  # new page with ...
                       height = rect.height)
        page1.show_pdf_page(rect, pdf, 0)  
        print(type(doc))
        print(type(page1))
        
        s3.Bucket(bucketname).put_object(Key=filename, Body=page1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the page1 object is defined using `fitz.fitz.page` and the type expected by S3 put object is bytes.

In order to solve the issue, you can use the `write` function of the new PDF (`doc`) and get the output of it which is in bytes format that you could pass to S3 then.

```py
# Save fil first.
new_bytes = doc.write()
s3.Bucket(bucketname).put_object(Key=filename, Body=new_bytes)
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: Would you happen to know now to properly apply a crop to the pdf using fitz

Comment: You are also my hero! I'll include my modification in an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason for me the `doc.write()` method didn't return a bytes object like stated above. Here's an additional way to create a new `doc`, convert to bytes using `BytesIO`, and then save it to `s3` as a `pdf`:

```py
import fitz
from io import BytesIO

client = boto3.client("s3")

# create new doc object
single_page = fitz.open()

# insert a page from original_pdf_doc
single_page.insert_pdf(
    original_pdf_doc, from_page=from_page_num, to_page=to_page_num
)

# Use BytesIO and .write() method to save to a bytes object
bytes_ = BytesIO(single_page.write())

# Upload the bytes object!
client.put_object(Body=bytes_, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```